# How to make image move to the right of the screen and back using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hi there,** I have an image of a sportscar on my webpage at [www.thetotempole.ca](http://thetotempole.ca/sportscar.html) that I'd like to move from the left of the screen, to the end of the right, and then turn around and go back left to it's original starting position. I have tried searching up how to do this and have had no luck.. Here is my HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #para1 { visibility: hidden; position:absolute; top:22px; left:307px;}
    #para2 { visibility: hidden; position:absolute; top:47px; left:307px;}
    #para3 { visibility: hidden; position:absolute; top:73px; left:307px;}
    #para4 { visibility: hidden; position:absolute; top:99px; left:307px;}
</style>
<script>
    var carleft = 0;

    function focuscolor(myinput)
    {
        myinput.style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
    }
    function blurcolor(myinput)
    {
        myinput.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    }
    function showhelp(mypara)
    {
        var para = document.getElementById(mypara);
        para.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    function hidehelp(mypara)
    {
        var para = document.getElementById(mypara);
        para.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    function startcar()
    {
        setInterval(movecar, 10);
    }
    function movecar()
    {
        carleft += 10;
        document.getElementById("car").style.left = carleft + "px";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="car" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left=0px" src="images/car.gif" onload="startcar()" />
    <p id="para1">Enter your first name.</p>
    <p id="para2">Enter your last name.</p>
    <p id="para3">Enter your address.</p>
    <p id="para4">Enter your phone number.</p>
    <form>
    <fieldset style="width:270px; background-color:lightblue;"><legend style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid blue;">Contact Form</legend>
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" onfocus="focuscolor(this); showhelp('para1')" onblur="blurcolor(this); hidehelp('para1')" /><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" onfocus="focuscolor(this); showhelp('para2')" onblur="blurcolor(this); hidehelp('para2')" /><br />
    Address: <input type="text" name="address" onfocus="focuscolor(this); showhelp('para3')" onblur="blurcolor(this); hidehelp('para3')" /><br />
    Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" onfocus="focuscolor(this); showhelp('para4')" onblur="blurcolor(this); hidehelp('para4')" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Send" /></fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is `CSS3-animations` an option?

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. I'd suggest calling startcar() after the page has loaded using something like JQuery $(document).ready(function(){});. Then you just need to add code to move the image back to it's start position after it reaches the right most position.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with `CSS3-animations` if you would like that option. I can guarantee that it is a lot less code then yours, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/8b8eN/show/. :p

Comment: Hmm it works but would it be possible to make it go to the right side of the screen and then reverse to move back to the left side? instead of making it go through the page and ending up on the left? Thanks.

Comment: Yupp one second, here you go http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/8b8eN/1/show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with `css-animations` but there is one thing I forgot to mention that may be important to you.

*`css-animations` are **not** supported by older browsers*

Here is the `HTML`,

```
<img src="http://i286.photobucket.com/albums/ll84/denisketje/lambo.png" alt="car" class="car" />
```

The `CSS`,

```
.car {
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-animation: Car 5s linear infinite;
   -moz-animation: Car 5s linear infinite;
   -ms-animation: Car 5s linear infinite;
   -o-animation: Car 5s linear infinite;
}
```

And finally the `keyframes`,

```
@-webkit-keyframes Car {
   from {
       left: -300px;
   }
   50% {
       left: 100%;
   }
   to { 
       left: -300px;
   }
}
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/8b8eN/2/show/) and remove the `show` in the url to see the code.

If you need me to explain how it works then I'd be happy to but just let me know.